# Extension for COGO for ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, extensions, cogo

I can't seem to find an answer with regards to obtaining COGO for ArcGIS Basic 10.2. Does COGO fall under any of the extensions currently offered by ESRI or does it only fall under the higher level licenses.

Comment: It is only available for ArcGIS Desktop Standard and ArcGIS Desktop Advanced. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m700000018000000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

COGO it is only available for ArcGIS Desktop Standard and ArcGIS Desktop Advanced

[image]

Matrix PDF

http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-desktop/~/media/files/pdfs/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis1021-desktop-functionality-matrix.pdf

Comment: Interesting! So are there any 3rd party extensions that will give me a similar tool?

Comment: +1 for the table. You might want to edit your question or ask a new one looking for a similar tool....or handy dandy google for the specific tool/function you are looking for

Comment: @rspencer38 Yes, there are 3rd party tools that replicate some or all of the functions of Esri's COGO tools. They vary in cost and support. The first that comes to mind is [ET Geotools](http://www.ian-ko.com/). There are several questions here with other options as well, including the Related questions over on the right. You might also look through the COGO tagged questions by clicking that tag - or a related tag depending on what you're wanting to do, such as [tag:land-survey] or [tag:metes-and-bounds]. Note that Basic *can* do direction/distance inputs without COGO - just not a traverse.